# Spivak, Chapter 5 (Limits), Lemma 2 Proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Preliminaries:

$$|x - x_0| < \min \left(1, \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|y_0| + 1)}\right)$$

$$|y - y_0| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|x_0| + 1)}$$

Proof:

$$|xy - x_0y_0| = |x(y-y_0) + y_0(x-x_0)|$$
$$\qquad \qquad \qquad \ \ \le |x| \cdot |y-y_0| + |y_0| \cdot |x-x_0|$$
$$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \ \ \lt (1 + |x_0|) \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|x_0| + 1)} + |y_0| \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|y_0| + 1)}$$
$$< \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon $$

My only hurdle in this proof understanding is how Spivak goes from

$|x| \cdot |y-y_0| + |y_0| \cdot |x-x_0|$

to

$|x| \cdot |y-y_0| + |y_0| \cdot |x-x_0| \lt (1 + |x_0|) \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|x_0| + 1)} + |y_0| \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|y_0| + 1)}$

It's clear that we are using the preliminaries here. But where did the `$\min$` go. Just full working out of steps here would be very appreciated.

Comment: $|x-x_{0}|\leq 1$ so $|x| - |x_{0}| \leq 1$. The min is just a short way of writing $|x-x_{0}|$ is bounded by both of those quantities.

Comment: looked at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225609/prove-that-xy-x-0y-0-epsilon?rq=1

Comment: and they use the fact that you mentioned @FZan, that  $|x| \leq (1 + |x_0|)$. This whole equation makes sense now